# How to submit a form thriugh ajax in rails3

Tags: jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I am using rails3, jquery-rails gem.

In my index page i m having the list of projects and form. when i submit the form through ajax call the i need to add the project to above list. I got the Ajax response as json. Then how to use this response to add the bottom of the above list.

Answer (score 2):

Using jQuery [`appendTo`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/)